# How to link a framework conditionally in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, dyld

I have a workspace with two projects:

1. **MySDK** (produces .framework)
2. **MyApp** (uses MySDK and produces .app file)

I'd like to link `MySDK` with only `MyConfig` configuration.
I tried to use `Other Linker Flags`:

```
-framework MySDK
```

but I always receive that:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MySDK.framework/MySDK   Referenced
>   from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/blabla/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: image not found

The desired MySDK.framework file is in `Build Products` folder: I tried to add `$($CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR)` to (everywhere) `Runpath Search Paths`, `Library Search Path` and everywhere that I could come up with. Still I receive dyld error.

On the internet there are many discussions about that but most of them are old, therefore I decided to try my chance by asking that again.

Answer (score 0):

Because $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR will not be available on your device, you must copy MySDK.framework inside MyApp.app, see [Copying Files While Building a Product](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/CreatingaCopyFilesBuildPhase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH14-SW1) and choose *Frameworks* as destination for MySDK.framework.

Also make sure that the *Runpath Search Paths* (LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS) build setting of your app target contains `@executable_path/Frameworks`.